# Tortoisehg doesn't show up in nautilus context menu

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, mercurial

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 on my netbook yesterday. I am having a problem getting tortoisehg working properly on it. I added the ppa for both [tortoisehg](https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/releases) and [mercurial](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases). I am able to install the software (tortoisehg, tortoisehg-nautilus) as I have done in past versions of ubuntu (not 11.04 - I skipped that version). When I launch nautilus and navigate to one of my repositories I don't see any context menu options for tortoisehg and I don't see any overlay icons indicating the repository status. I know tortoisehg is installed because I can issue the thg command at a terminal and the workbench shows up.

Any ideas on how to get things working?

Comment: I am wondering if anyone knows how to set up the context menus manually?

Comment: check my answer it's pretty close to how Tortoisehg was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to relate to [bug #859104: Nautilus extensions written in Python do not work in Oneiric](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/859104). Unfortunately the solution seems to be that someone needs to rewrite the tortoisehg Nautilus extension.

Answer (score 8):

I have this problem too so I wrote something to fix it.

just run this in the terminal to set up

```
START=$(pwd)
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/zeitue/nautilus-mercurial-scripts
mv nautilus_mercurial_scripts/Mercurial/ .
rm -Rf nautilus_mercurial_scripts/
cd $START
```

OK done, now just right click the folder/repo and look under scripts

Comment: Good enough for me. Should be marked as an answer.

Comment: This works quite well for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for writing this. For anyone using ubuntu 13.04 you need to put the scripts in the /home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ in order for nautilus to find them.

Answer (score 4):

I was researching this myself. It may be related to [a bug in nautilus-python running on Oneiric](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-python/+bug/858925). In the description, there is mention of a possible related bug with a similar context menu issue in another application.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug reported on TortoiseHG bugtracker: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1333/ubuntu-1110-tortoisehg-doesnt-show-up-in.

Answer (score 2):

I managed make it work it rather easily by using the tortoisehg ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
(nautilus:2750): Nautilus-Python-WARNING **: g_module_open libpython failed: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct')
```

On your .xsession-errors file at home directory maybe this could help you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/1202823

Good luck